# Firing up a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Ok so i have this [page](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/)  and if you look at the second dropdown...i want to fire up a tooltip or something when the user tries to select the second dropdown before the fire...otherwise i do the slidetoggle

```
$('.real_business_select .trigger').click(function(){ 
    if($("#industry_category_id").val() != ""){
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('select-active');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.drop-down').slideToggle();
    }else{
        //fire some tooltip....any ideas
    }
    return false;
});
```

any ideas on a good simple solution....im trying to find a good solution that will only fire when i need it too and not everytime the user hovers over the element..any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). It's a jQuery addon that does wonderful things. You could provide any event as tooltip activators.